# Java VNC Libraries

Tags: java, vnc

Are there any VNC Libraries for Java, I need to build a JSP/Servlet based VNC server, to allow user to share their desktops with helpdesk. I've seen jVNC, but i'd like to build it myself, for a University project.

In particular, I'm looking for Java Libraries that I can use inside another servlet based application. Unfortuatnely tight VNC's source is in C.

Comment: There is TightVNC source in Java (as for now).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you looked at the tightVNC source?  It is fairly terse  http://www.tightvnc.com/download.html