# Desktop Sharing and Chat open source

Tags: c#, java, c++, video-streaming, desktop-sharing

I need library or ready to use open source desktop sharing and chat application in C#, C++ or Java. I should use this in my project.

I see real vnc is not open source anymore? don't suggest real vnc.

Please suggest most SIMPLE and easy to use library/application.

Comment: What do you mean it's [not opensource](http://www.realvnc.com/vnc/why.html) ?

Comment: People often write 'open source' when they actually mean 'free'.  The two are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php)

Also take a look at these questions on stackoverflow
 [How can I display a VNC Viewer in a Java rich client (LGPL, Apache, MIT license)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463397/how-can-i-display-a-vnc-viewer-in-a-java-rich-client-lgpl-apache-mit-license)
[Java VNC Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504/java-vnc-libraries)